# Android: Unwanted Delay in Translate Animation in API 19

Tags: android

I am quite new to Android as well as StackOverflow. I have animated a programmatically created TextView here, but it displays the final state of my TextView (i.e the state after which the animation is finished) for a fraction of a second before playing the animation in API 19 and that makes it lose its visual appeal instantly. However, it works fine in API 22. Any help will be appreciated. I have also put the code of my animation resource file, my layout resource file and my Java class for the same.

Code for my animation resource file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<set android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" android:fillBefore="false">
    <alpha
           android:duration="1200"
           android:fromAlpha="0.0"
           android:toAlpha="1.0"
        />
    <translate
               android:duration="1200"
               android:fromYDelta="70%p"
               android:toYDelta="0%p"/>
</set>

</set>
```

Code for my layout resource file is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">
```

Code for my Java file is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 70);
        //tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        tv.setText("My Text");
        layout.addView(tv);
        Animation fadeUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_up);
        tv.startAnimation(fadeUp);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your TextView initially to 'invisible' in the xml:

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

Then in your onCreate method add just before your animation:

```
tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

See how that performs - if there is still a 'flick' then replace the above line with:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }, 20);
```

Basically this will ensure the animation starts 20 milliseconds before the TextView is visible.

Comment: It seems that the Cyanogen ROM in the phone (YU AO5510) has its own bugs since my app runs fine in other phones with API 19. Despite that, this answer helped me a lot in sequencing views so that I can animate them one by one. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
android:fillEnabled="true"
android:fillBefore="true"
android:fillAfter="true"
```

to your set. Note also that you have two `set` elements in your animation, which makes no sense - get rid of the outer one.

The fill attributes make the layout position of the view be fixed to your `from` and `to` declaration. So before the animation start you'll stay at `70%p`, and after at `0%p`.
If this does not work either, maybe you should consider using visibility.